# Django POST handler receives different JSON than what I send

Tags: python, json, django

I have a Django POST handler like this:

```
class FooListView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        fields = request.POST
        foo = self.Foo.objects.create(**fields)
        json = serializers.serialize('json', [foo])
        return JsonResponse(json, safe=False)
```

And a unit test like this:

```
class FooTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.url = '/foo/'
        self.fields = {'foo': 'bar'}

    def test_post_data(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.url, data=self.fields)
        data = json.loads(response.json())
        self.assertEqual(self.fields, data[0]['fields'])
```

In IntelliJ, I set a break point on the first lines of `test_post_data()` and `post()`. Inspecting `self.fields` in `test_post_data()` shows the dict that I set it to. But then when I inspect `fields` in `post()`, it's value is `<QueryDict: {'foo': ['bar']}>`. I see the correct key in this `QueryDict`, but now the value is a **list** containing the string that I sent from the test. Why is the value changed from what I sent?

p.s. My model is like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Comment: Don't you explicitly make it a list here? json = serializers.serialize('json', [foo])

Comment: @AlexanderDavydov 1. That is a list of Model objects. 2. That occurs **after** the mysterious change to my JSON.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the way that [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) works. It allows multiple values for the same key. It means it can handle data like `a=1&a=2&b=1`.

You can get the `request.POST.get('key')` to get the item, or `request.POST.getlist('key')` to get a list (in your case it will be a list with one item).

Comment: I want the POST handler to receive JSON in the body of the HTTP request. Is `request.POST` not the correct way to do this?

Comment: `request.POST` only works for form-encoded data. If you want to post json data then you should do `self.client.post(self.url, json.dumps(self.fields), content_type="application/json")`. Then in your view, use `json.loads(request.body)` instead of `request.POST`.

Comment: "A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters, **providing that the request contains form data.**" Oops, I missed that on my first 20 readings. Thanks.